# Update/remove element in sitemap.xml

Tags: xml, gridview

i wonder how can i update and remove element in sitemap.xml when it's loaded in Gridview.

I wish i can remove selected element or update it. pls advice.

The following is how i load sitemap.xml to Gridview.

```
Protected Sub BindGrid()

    Dim DS As New DataSet()
    Dim DT As New DataTable()

    DS.ReadXml(MapPath("~/Sitemap.xml"))

    If DS IsNot Nothing AndAlso DS.HasChanges() = True Then
        DS.Tables(0).DefaultView.Sort = "priority ASC"
        Me.GridView.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
        Me.GridView.DataBind()
    Else
        Me.GridView.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

This is my sitemap.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://yourdomain.com/product/gameboy/</loc>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://yourdomain.com/product/sony-ps5/</loc>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://yourdomain.com/product/xbox-360/</loc>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

This is my existing code but doesn't work for me.

```
    Protected Sub BulkDelete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In Me.GridView.Rows

        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            Dim isChecked As Boolean = row.Cells(0).Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().FirstOrDefault().Checked

            If isChecked Then

                Dim xmldoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Sitemap.xml"))
                xmldoc.Root.Elements("urlset").Where(Function(p) p.Element("loc").Value = GridView.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value).Remove()
                xmldoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Sitemap.xml"))

            End If

        End If

    Next

    Me.btn_bulk_update.Visible = False
    Me.btn_bulk_delete.Visible = False

    BindGrid()

End Sub
```